# MVVM binding with collections in Model

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding

I have a problem with correct implementing MVVM pattern in my Terminal application.
The application prints out all data received via serial port in specified format.
So `Model` part should be responsible for collecting data while `ViewModel` should be responsible for holding `View` format configuration (data with DateTime timestamp, Time timestamp, data in HEX or ASCII).
But on the other hand `Model` also can save data to a file, so it also needs information about storage format, so it should rather be in `Model`, not in `ViewModel`. Is this conception correct?

The other problem is that `Model` needs to have collection with all received data. I have read that `ObservableCollection` should not be used in `Model`, but without `ObservableCollection` I have a problem how to inform `ViewModel` and `View` that data hase changed.
Should `ViewModel` keep its own copy of data in `ObservableCollection`? How should I correctly bind it to `ListBox`?

Comment: `MVVM` in a `CLI`, first time for everything I guess!

Comment: The ViewModel should be responsible only for the view(s). The model should have all the other logic. And yes, view model should have it's own copy of ObservableCollection which should ideally hold only the values that are to be displayed on the UI, on the other hand, your model need not have an ObservableCollection, you can have a List or IEnumerable in the model. ObservableCollections automatically notify if anything changes inside the collection and this is required only for the UI and not in the business layer.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using an `ObservableCollection<T>` in a model. If you want your model to notify listeners when some collection changes, then just use that. However, the default implementation of the `ObservableCollection<T>` has a drawback: it lacks an `AddRange` (or similar) method. If you're going to bulk-insert entries an such a collection, you need to extend the default implementation.

Comment: @Raviraj Palvankar but how should `Model` inform `ViewModel` that its collection has been changed? Without `ObservableCollection` I need to create some events which will be subsribed by `ViewModel`.

Comment: If more than one objects are making changes to your Model then you can use the INotifyPropertyChanged and the view model will register to the property changed events. If you don’t have a reference to the model properties then you can use a messaging system so send and subscribe events through the messenger.